# Python sh import causing Unresolved Import error in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, shell, pydev

I'm using sh in python 2.7.5 to call shell programs like `curl` and `mkdir`, but in PyDev plugin 2.7.5 under Eclipse 4.3.0. the following line gives an `Unresolved Import` error:

```
from sh import curl, printenv, mkdir, cat
```

I'm able to run the above code in a python shell. I do have the path to `sh` included in the `Libraries` pane in the `Interpreter - Python` window in Preferences, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call console commands. For example:

```
from subprocess import call
dir_name = '/foo/bar/'
call('mkdir %s'%dir_name, shell=True)
```

Comment: I'll consider using this if I can't get sh imports to be recognized correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like Bill said, subprocess is a good choice here. I'd personally recommend using the Popen because it doesn't block, and allows you to wait for commands to finish with its communicate() method, which also returns stdout and stderr. Also, avoid using shell=True when possible. Usage:

```
import subprocess
testSubprocess = subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', dir_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
testOut, testErr = testSubprocess.communicate()
```